# make searching for source in wrong directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I searched quite a bit to find the solution for this but no luck.
I have some source code that produces HTML and am using a `Makefile` for this. The directory structure is:

```
main/
main/Makefile
main/src
main/src/dox
main/src/dox/generate.rb
...
```

The relevant portion of the Makefile is:

```
sources := $(shell find src -name "*rb" )
pages := $(sources:src/%.rb=%.html)

all: $(pages)

%.html: src/%.rb
        ruby $< > $@
```

`make -dr` produces:

```
(snip)
Considering target file 'dox/generate.html'.
   File 'dox/generate.html' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'dox/generate.html'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'generate'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'dox/src/generate.rb'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'generate'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'dox/src/generate.rb'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'dox/src/generate.rb'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   No implicit rule found for 'dox/generate.html'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'dox/generate.html'.
  Must remake target 'dox/generate.html'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'dox/generate.html', needed by 'build'.  Stop.`
```

How can I correct this?

Clearly, `make` is looking for the source file in the wrong directory, but the rule seems very simple and straightforward.

Comment: Why is it clearly wrong? You have told it that `foo/bar.html` depends on `src/foo/bar.rb`

Comment: Yes, but that is not where make is looking. See the debugging output. Also, I tried to use John's information by changing the rule to:: `./%.html: src/%.rb ruby $< > $@` but I still get the same output. I want this rule to be general so I don't have to specify every subdirectory in src matched with a corresponding directory.

Comment: I finally came up with a workaround. I created a symlink at the top level to . with:
ln -s . top
Then I changed the rule to:
top/%.html: src/%.rb
    ruby $< > $@

That tricked make into working correctly. The problem is that a workaround was needed in the first place.

Comment: BTW, I see two potential problems in your example which are not necessarily related to the question: `find` is looking for `*rb` and will also find files like `abcrb` or `foo.superb`. `find` should look for `*.rb`. And in cases where `$@` is in a subdirectory and that subdirectory does not exist yet, your make recipe must create that subdirectory before failing to write the target file into a non-existing directory with `> $@`. Adding a first line to a recipe like `@test -d $(@D) || mkdir -p $(@D)` or simply `@mkdir -p $(@D)` is an often used solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly, make is looking for the source file in the wrong directory but the rule seems very simple and straightforward.

"Wrong" in the sense of "not the directory you want it to look in", of course.  There is no actual misbehavior here, in that `make` is behaving exactly as [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match).

When `make` considers the pattern rule in the question for building target `dox/generate.html`, the pattern matches with *stem* `dox/generate`.  **When the target pattern does not have any literal directory components**, as in this case, the leading directory portion of that stem gets special treatment:

> When prerequisites are turned into file names, the directories from the stem are added at the front, while the rest of the stem is substituted for the '%'.

(GNU make manual)

This is how GNU `make` supports pattern rules structured for building targets in the same directory as their corresponding source, whatever directory that may be.  This is the traditional approach for `make`-based build systems.

And that is why you see `make` looking for file `dox/src/generate.rb` when the stem is `dox/generate.html` and the prerequisite pattern is `src/%.html`.

It's unclear what other files you want to build with this rule, but possibly this is what you're looking for:

```
dox/%.html: src/dox/%.rb
        ruby $< > $@
```

When, as there, the target pattern does have an explicit leading directory component, the stem is treated as a flat string, with no special treatment of directory components.

Comment: Actually, I was wanting:

dox/%.html: src/dox/%.rb
        ruby $< > $@

so maybe my rule should be:

./%.html: src/%.rb
        ruby $< > $@

Comment: @ariel, if the first of those does what you want then I recommend going with that.  It's clearer.  Also, if the first works then the second won't.  The `./` in the second's target pattern would need to match explicitly.

Comment: Updated the recommended rule at the end of this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this rule so I don't need a separate one for every subdirectory in src?

Comment: @ariel, if you need to handle arbitrary subdirectories of `src/` in this way, not just subdirectories of `src/dox/`, then I expect your `./%.html` alternative could be made to work by modifying the target names you want to build.  As I said, the leading `./` would need to match explicitly, so maybe `pages := $(sources:src/%.rb=./%.html)`.

Comment: Tried that but still no joy. Make "cleverly" recognizes the path for what it is and gives the same errors as noted. If you have to "trick" your tool into working correctly by avoiding one of it's "features" the tool is poorly designed. This is because of its "special" handling of certain cases. Documenting bad design doesn't make it good design.

Comment: Ah.  I stumbled over a GNU-ism there, @ariel.  My apologies.  My claim that the `./` must be matched explicitly is true in traditional `make`, but GNU make actually treats `./foo` as equivalent to `foo`.  Apparently that extends to its interpretation of pattern rules.  What I described works for any destination folder other than `.`, but it does not work for `.`.